# What's the advantage of using $splice (from immutability-helper) over filter to remove an item from an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/) for doing CRUD operations on state data and want to know if I should always use `$splice` for removing data or is it ok to use `filter` (since it's not destructive)?

For example, let's say I have an array of objects:

```
todos = [
 {id: 1, body: "eat"},
 {id: 2, body: "drink"},
 {id: 3, body: "sleep"},
 {id: 4, body: "run"}
]
```

Given an item id, I can remove it in two ways:

a. find its `index` and use `$splice`:

```
index = todos.findIndex((t) => { return(t.id === id) });
newtodos = update(todos, { $splice: [[index, 1]] })
```

OR

b. use `filter`:

```
newtodos = todos.filter((t) => { return(t.id === id) });
```

`filter` is more concise but I'm not sure if it has any disadvantages compared to using `$splice` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `immutability-helper`:

it's convenient to process `nested collection`:

```js
const collection = [1, 2, { todos: [...todos] }];
const newCollection = update(collection, {
  2: {
    todos: {
      $apply: todos => todos.filter(t => t.id !== id)
    }
  }
});
```

and, it give you a new copy for `collection` and `collection[2]`:

```js
console.log(newCollection === collection, newCollection[2] === collection[2]);
//false false
```

So, if you use `react-redux`, `connect` state to component, if you want your component **re-render** when the state changed, you must return a new copy of state.

Do this operator with old way:

```js
const todoList = collection[2].todos;
const idx = todoList.findIndex(t => t.id === id);
const newTodoList = update(todoList, { $splice: [[index, 1]] });
const newCollectionTwo = [...collection];
newCollectionTwo[2] = {
  todos: newTodoList
};
```

and take a look with console:

```
console.log(collection, newCollectionTwo, collection === newCollectionTwo, collection[2] === newCollectionTwo[2]);
```

for simple data structure and operator, i think it's equal with `filter`.

Sorry for my English is not good, and this is my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @novaline. I hadn't thought of using filter with $apply.

Comment: @J.Doe I think the point is return new copy of reference type data for your operator path